# odoo 14 public URL for pdf files open without authentication

Tags: odoo-14

I create a binary field Also generate report pdf. Everything is working correctly,

But I want to create *a public URL link* for these files How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using controllers without authentication, and then return a PDF like Odoo does but using sudo enviroment.

Please show some code to help you properly.